# JQuery UI Datepicker: auto-popup return date on selection of departure date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have two input fields on which the user can specify departure and return dates.

I am trying to implement a situation where when the user selects a departure date, the datepicker automatically pops up on the return date.

Below is what I have at the moment, which is not working.

The HTML:

```
<input id="departure-date" type="text">
<input id="return-date" type="text">
```

The (JQuery) Javascript:

```
$(function() {
   $('#departure-date').datepicker({
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      showAnim: "fold",
      showButtonPanel: true,
      onSelect: (function(){ 
        this.val(date.toLocaleDateString());
        $('#return-date').focus();  
      })
   });

   $('#return-date').datepicker({
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      showAnim: "fold",
      showButtonPanel: true,
      onSelect: (function(){ 
        this.val(date.toLocaleDateString());    
      })
   });
});
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to work will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like

```js
$(function() {
  $('#departure-date').datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showAnim: "fold",
    showButtonPanel: true,
    onSelect: (function(date) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#return-date').datepicker('show');
      }, 300)
      $(this).val($(this).datepicker('getDate').toLocaleDateString());
    })
  });

  $('#return-date').datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showAnim: "fold",
    showButtonPanel: true,
    onSelect: (function(date) {
      $(this).val($(this).datepicker('getDate').toLocaleDateString());
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="departure-date" type="text">
<input id="return-date" type="text">
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6u43xarm/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the value of the datepicker whenever value changes.

```
$(function() {
   $('#departure-date').datepicker({
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      showAnim: "fold",
      showButtonPanel: true,
      onSelect: (function(){ 
        $('#return-date').focus();  
      })
   });

   $('#return-date').datepicker({
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      showAnim: "fold",
      showButtonPanel: true,
      onSelect: (function(){ 

      })
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#departure-date').datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showAnim: "fold",
    showButtonPanel: true,
    onSelect: (function(date) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#return-date').datepicker('show');
      }, 300)
      $(this).val($(this).datepicker('getDate').toLocaleDateString());
    })
  });

  $('#return-date').datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showAnim: "fold",
    showButtonPanel: true,
    onSelect: (function(date) {
      $(this).val($(this).datepicker('getDate').toLocaleDateString());
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="departure-date" type="text">
<input id="return-date" type="text">
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.